# Change checkbox in jquery not working in text! template in backbone.js

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I have a view, using text! template to render the html in my web page. In my `quote.html` of text!, I have one form :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   alert("outside checkbox event");
   $('input[name=chkVAT]').change(function(){
      if($('input[name=chkVAT]').is(':checked')){
         alert('Checked');
      } else {
         alert('Not checked');
      }
    });
});
<form>
   .......
   <input type="checkbox" name="chkVAT" id="chkVAT" />
   <div id="valVAT"><%=VAT%>
</form>
```

There is only `alert("outside checkbox event")` is working. I don't know why others 3 alert is not working.

Any idea please. Thanks.

Comment: Is there actually a `input[name=chkVAT]` on the page when you `$('input[name=chkVAT]')`? I'd guess that there isn't.

Comment: View source from my browser : `<input name="chkVAT" id="chkVAT" type="checkbox">`

Comment: But what is `$('input[name=chkVAT]').length` right after the outer `alert` call?

Comment: @muistooshort : So how can I solve it?

Comment: Put `input[name=chkVAT]` inside your view's `el` and hook it up using the view's `events`. Basically, use Backbone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not Backbone-way. Are you sure that checkbox already rendered on document ready?

```
Backbone.View.extend({
  template : _.template('your form'),
  events : {
    'change [name=chkVAT]' : 'checkboxChangeHandler'
  },
  checkboxChangeHandler : function () {
    alert('changed');
  }
});
```

working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vpetrychuk/tXdxm/1/)

Comment: So I cannot do that in my html template?

Comment: @Vitaliy Petrychuk : your code is working, but I can not do that in my html template?

Comment: @VitaliyPetrychuk: please see my jsFiddle dear, that's my `render` block in my view, I'm doing that, then got `VAT is not definded` error.

Comment: which fiddle? your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tXdxm/) is not real backbone stuff. What @VitaliyPetrychuk proposed is good one. What problem do you have still?

Comment: @user10, sorry my bad. But it is complicated to show it in jsFiddle, that's why I just did a typo at `http://jsfiddle.net/tXdxm/4/`, @Vitaliy Petrychuck solution is working but it is not what I had in my view, I just added `render` block to jsFiddle, I hope you're not mind to have a look please. Thanks.

Comment: why are you listening `change` event on ready function? You should listen it inside your view as described by @VitaliyPetrychuk, if you are going to build real backbone app. Anyway, to resolve this problem you should call `render` function inside `document.ready`, then listen for `change` event.

Comment: @user10 : I listen `change` event on ready function, because I separate my template into `.html`, then I loop data in that `html` template.

Comment: @Domo proper way is you should render that template in your view. and you should listen change event in your view. If you didn't render your template in view, where did you insert your template into DOM?

Comment: Okay it makes sense now.Due to VitaliyPetrychuk's jsFiddle and @user10 explanation, my problem was solved. Thanks you so much :)